# Hi I have a requirement to capturing sql server query execution output from message tab from ssms using powershell.Any leads?

Tags: powershell

Hi I  have a requirement to capturing SQL server query execution  output from message tab  from ssms using powershell .Any leads ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAtme.png)

Comment: Just check for `Invoke-SqlCmd`. Something like `$QueryResults = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "host\dbinstance" -Database "db" -Query $Query`

Comment: Invoke-SqlCmd is the definite command  to run tsql statement via power shell for sure.I am able to capture the query out put error in case the execution fails but not the details from message tab.That is my exact requirement

Comment: Even with `-verbose -IncludeSqlUserErrors` ? With MSSQL19, `Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "host\dbinstance" -Database "lydb" -Query "SELECT 1/0;"  -verbose -IncludeSqlUserErrors` outputs the expected error message.

Comment: You got me wrong.I am looking for capturing details from the message tab as shown in the screenshot.Query execution error I am able to capture.

Answer (score 0):

Include the `-StatisticsVariable` parameter when calling `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlet and declare a string that will be assigned to a variable once the cmdlet has executed.

Ex `-StatisticsVariable "StatVar"`

Then just call up the variable to view the output `$StatVar`